# What should I include in Granted Service Units in CCR-U? All rating groups or reported rating groups or requested services?

Tags: diameter-protocol

I couldn't find specific scenario related this case in RFC 4006(Obsolate). They have made it clear in latest RFC 8506.

For example I granted quota for rating group 0 and 1(CCA-I). Now gateway reports used quota(CCR-U) for rating group 0. Should I send(CCA-U) all available quota again in answer or should I send the one that got reported along with requested service units for different rating group?

At this point I am sending all the available rating groups in CCA-U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always respond to the Rating Groups which were requested.

I don't have a reference to the RFC but below a dump from a real-life flow. See CCA's containing only RGs which were listed in the CCR's:

[image]